# How to create 2 column grid system with ng-repeat in Ionic Framework?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I am new to Ionic Framework. I have to show products in a 2-column grid system using ng-repeat. How can I implement `<ion-row>` after every 2 products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can use 2 column grid in ng-repeat

```
<ion-grid fixed>
    <ion-row>
        <ion-col size="6" *ngFor="let item of items">{{item}}</ion-col>
    </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

Comment: @KamalK. please mark it as the answer  (tick mark) and upvote it (up arrow)